# Is stopping a Docker Container the same as removing a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, containers

If Docker is "ephemeral", how is stopping a container different than removing a container?  When I stop and I start, that doesn't mean I can save information in that container does it?  I thought that was what you didn't want to do (save data in the Container.)

Answer (score 2):

> If Docker is "ephemeral", how is stopping a container different than
>   removing a container?

Stopped containers are visible via `docker ps -a`. If containers are started with the `--rm` option, they'll remove themselves after stopping.

> When I stop and I start, that doesn't mean I can save information in
>   that container does it? I thought that was what you didn't want to do
>   (save data in the Container.)

You're absolutely right. State should never be saved inside a container.

Comment: If I stop a Docker Container, is State saved?

Comment: Well, go look. It depends on how the container was started, which you'd understand if you read my answer. This isn't really a question you should be asking, though, because you should never care about state inside a container. If you *do* care about it, you're using docker incorrectly.

Comment: I only care because other than waiting for transactions or the like to complete, I do not see why I couldn't simply remove a running container instead of waiting for it to stop and then remove it

Comment: Well, if something is running in that container that you need, then don't stop it. If nothing is running that you care about, then stop/remove it.

Comment: Can't I skip stop and just remove?

Comment: @johnny Please. Just read the documentation. Strive to *understand* the systems you're working with. **Try things**. Build up a test system you can play with to try out these things you're asking about. We don't spoon-feed here. If you're wondering if you can skip the "stop" step, just try it!

Comment: @EEAA most unuseful answer and subsequent comments. Thanks. Actual answer is here: hhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362856/whats-the-difference-between-docker-stop-and-docker-rm

Comment: @Xiler I agree, very unhelpful response to the OP who is trying to learn something new he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

When stopping a container it is possible to restart the container later again with `docker start <ID|name>`. If the container was not started with some special options the internal data was retained and one can continue to use it. Can you self test this behavior with the docker registry:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
# deploy a local docker image
curl -X GET http://<youthostname>:5000/v2/_catalog
docker stop registry
docker start registry
curl -X GET http://<youthostname>:5000/v2/_catalog
# the content is still there
```

Answer (score 0):

When a container is started, tools like docker create a directory with:

- the configuration (name, volume mounts, published ports, etc)
- a container specific filesystem layer and the assembled filesystem from the container layer merged with the image layers
- log output when using the json or local log drivers

When the container is stopped, the running environment with various namespaces and cgroups is destroyed, but it can be restarted with the previous filesystem state and same configuration.

When the container is removed, you can recreate it, but filesystem changes, logs, and any other configuration data would be lost.

Here's a quick example showing the filesystem persistence:

```
$ docker run -it --name stop-test busybox /bin/sh
/ # cat /hello.txt
cat: can't open '/hello.txt': No such file or directory
/ # echo "hello world" > /hello.txt
/ # cat /hello.txt
hello world
/ # exit

$ docker container inspect stop-test --format '{{json .State}}' | jq .
{
  "Status": "exited",
  "Running": false,
  "Paused": false,
  "Restarting": false,
  "OOMKilled": false,
  "Dead": false,
  "Pid": 0,
  "ExitCode": 0,
  "Error": "",
  "StartedAt": "2023-08-16T14:52:49.810997424Z",
  "FinishedAt": "2023-08-16T14:53:09.900172563Z"
}

$ docker start stop-test
stop-test

$ docker attach stop-test
/ # cat /hello.txt
hello world
/ # exit

$ docker rm stop-test
stop-test

$ docker run -it --name stop-test busybox /bin/sh
/ # cat /hello.txt
cat: can't open '/hello.txt': No such file or directory
/ # exit

$ docker run -it --name stop-test busybox /bin/sh
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/stop-test" is already in use by container "caaad3a5287431dc6a9a924c658723580298d182d4b27bd8ed3fcd6c3690b2ad". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Note that if you want to store data between containers, a volume would be preferred. And if you want to view logs of deleted containers, pushing those logs to an external system, like elastic, would be needed.